# What is the simplest way to get user input in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I want to get some user input, process it a little and present the same to the user. I need not save the inout to the database. What is the simplest way to do that in Django

Comment: Follow the django tutorial. It essentially does it for you.

Answer (score 1):

In the html template

```
<form method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.name of field in forms.py }}
</form>
```

In the views.py

```
if request.POST:
        form = formName(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
               variable: form.cleaned_data['name of field in forms.py']
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a simple example

## views.py

```
def test_form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.POST.get('username')
        if user == "mark":
            return HttpResponse('hello mark')

    return render(request, "form.html")
```

## urls.py

```
path ('form/', test_form, name="form")
```

## form.html

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'form' %}">{% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```